# Color Calibration in Ubuntu and Xerox 8570 printer

Tags: printing, colors

The thumbnail size images show normal color of object. After double-clicking an image, appears off-color like it's shaded red. Printed photos are also off color. Ubuntu color setting states Xerox Phaser 8500DN is uncalibrated. I've been searching and searching and can't find any hints on how to fix this. My knowledge regarding Ubuntu (& PC's) is on the low side of moderate. I don't want to keep downloading stuff I know nothing about - any suggestions out there beside throwing my computer out the window.

Answer (score 0):

Little theory. For each device, printer or monitor there is a ICC profile (ICC profile is a set of data that characterizes a color input or output device, or a color space (C) Wiki). If you want to find a match you can change settings of printer or monitor or both. As I understand you want to change only monitor settings. First of all try using different viewers, they can give different output on the same monitor. Second, check that problem is realy in output devices, not in pictures itself.

There is a usefull tool for managing ICC profiles, for sure it will help with monitor, check if it can help with printer. https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/gnome-color-manager/